# How to find a Mail-Session-Object using WLST

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I have two WLST-Scripts: the first creates a new Mail-Session doing something like this:

```
fooMailSession = cmo.createMailSession('FooMailSession')
fooMailSession.setJNDIName('mail/FooMailSession')
(...)
```

In the other script I want to remove/delete the earlier created Mail Session - but how can I get securely access to the object and what is the method to remove it?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *lookupMailSession(String name)*

```
mailSession = cmo.lookupMailSession('FooMailSession')
cmo.destroyMailSession(mailSession)
```